# Generically converting between two case classes of the same shape

Tags: scala, shapeless, case-class

I have a bunch of case classes that have identically shaped counterparts in other sealed traits (each sealed trait is used for exhaustive pattern matching in Akka Typed behaviors) and I want to convert from one version to the next with the least boilerplate.

The traits look something like this:

```
object RoutingCommands {
  sealed trait Command
  final case class ProtocolMsg(name: String, id: Int) extends Command
}

object ProtocolCommands {
  sealed trait Command
  final case class ProtocolMsg(name: String, id: Int) extends Command
}
```

I know I can do the conversion using `shapeless.Generic` like this:

```
val msg1 = ProtocolCommands.ProtocolMsg("foo", 1)
val msg2 = Generic[RoutingCommands.ProtocolMsg].from(
  Generic[ProtocolCommands.ProtocolMsg].to(msg1)
)
```

But having to do that for every conversion is more boilerplate than just
constructing the case classes by hand. Ideally, I'd like a converter that derives the above code based on the two types provided at compile time, such as `val msg2 = convert(msg1)`

As a step toward that I tried to break it down to something like:

```
def convert[A,B](a: A): B = Generic[B].from(
  Generic[A].to(a)
)
```

but that results in:

```
Error:(55, 44) could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic[B]
```

From digging around, it seems I need to use `Generic.Aux` which lead me to:

```
def convert[A, B, HL <: HList](a: A)(
  implicit
  genA: Generic.Aux[A, HL],
  genB: Generic.Aux[B, HL]
) = genB.from(genA.to(a))
```

Which, when called with:

```
val msg3 = convert(msg2)
```

results in:

```
Error:(61, 57) could not find implicit value for parameter genB: shapeless.Generic.Aux[B,HL]
```

This is understandable since nowhere is the return type defined. However, I figure out how to provide a hint what `B` is so that `genB` can be derived implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "partial application"

```
def convert[A, HL <: HList](a: A)(
  implicit
  genA: Generic.Aux[A, HL]
) = new Helper(a, genA)

class Helper[A, HL <: HList](a: A, genA: Generic.Aux[A, HL]) {
  def apply[B](implicit genB: Generic.Aux[B, HL]) = genB.from(genA.to(a))
}

val msg3 = convert(msg2).apply[ProtocolCommands.ProtocolMsg]
```

(it's better to use "partial application" from @Ben's answer)

or create a type class

```
trait Convert[A, B] {
  def apply(a: A): B
}

object Convert {
  implicit def mkConvert[A, B, HL <: HList](implicit
    genA: Generic.Aux[A, HL],
    genB: Generic.Aux[B, HL]
  ): Convert[A, B] = a => genB.from(genA.to(a))
}

implicit class ConvertOps[A](a: A) {
  def convert[B](implicit cnv: Convert[A, B]): B = cnv(a)
}

val msg3 = msg2.convert[ProtocolCommands.ProtocolMsg]
```

https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:ops:migration "6.3 Case study: case class migrations"

Comment: Loving the typeclass approach. Thanks! Time to read more shapeless docs to get a better understanding for how this all works

Answer (score 2):

As you suggested, the problem is that the result type isn't specified and can't be inferred. You *could* fix this by providing the type parameters explicitly, as in

```
val msg3 = convert[ProtocolCommands.ProtocolMsg, RoutingCommands.ProtocolMsg, String :: Int :: HNil](msg2)
```

but this obviously defeats the point of using Shapeless. The compiler only needs the return type to be specified explicitly, and can infer the others, but Scala doesn't directly support providing only a subset of type arguments explicitly.

As mentioned in a previous answer you can use partial application to work around this limitation using the "partially applied" pattern. This works best if you use a class parameterised on the return type, which is what you need to specify, rather than the input type:

```
def convert[B] = new ConvertPartiallyApplied[B]

class ConvertPartiallyApplied[B] {
  def apply[A, Repr](a: A)(implicit genA: Generic.Aux[A, Repr], genB: Generic.Aux[B, Repr]) = genB.from(genA.to(a))
}
```

which can then be used simply with

```
convert[RoutingCommands.ProtocolMsg](msg2)
```